# How to list all items defined in a predefined enviroment

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, environments

Code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
\date{\today}

\linespread{1.5}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Zadanie]{\begin{trivlist}
        \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\begin{document}
    \clearpage\maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty} \newpage 

     \tableofcontents \newpage

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \section{Struktura } 
    \begin{problem}{1}

    \end{problem}


\end{document}
```

So i have defined a problem environment. How to create something like table of contents but it would list all of those problems e.g. Problem 1, Problem 2, Problem 3, Problem 4... simply toc but with problems defined with use of problem environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `etoc` package can do that: from `§16, Arbitrary “Lists Of...”, \etoctoccontentsline`:

> Example: imagine a document with dozens of exercises, perhaps defined as
>   \newtheorem{exercise}{}[section] .
>
> Let us explain how to instruct etoc to display an hyperlinked list of
>   all these exercises. For this we put in the preamble:

```
\newtheorem{exerci}{}[section]
% the exercice number will be recoverable via \etocname: v--here--v
\newcommand*{\exercisetotoc}{\etoctoccontentsline{exercise}{\theexerci}}
\newenvironment{exercise}{\begin{exerci}\exercisetotoc}{\end{exerci}}
\etocsetlevel{exercise}{6}
```

> In this way, \etocname will give the exercise number (but \etocnumber
>   will be empty).